# Integer.parseInt reformat string?

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I'm building my custom application for Android. I have implemented a `datepicker` dialog which it takes time when a time is picked. The problem is that time picker doesn't format correctly what I select (for example if `03` is selected, `datepicker` returns `3`).

For fixing this issue I've implemented this code:

```
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {

            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            long date = calendarView.getDate();
            DateFormat df = new DateFormat();

            String format = (String) df.format("dd/MM/yyyy", date);

            Date hourdate = new Date();

            hourdate.setHours(hour);
            hourdate.setMinutes(minute);


            SimpleDateFormat hourformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
            SimpleDateFormat minuteformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

            String formattedhour = hourformatter.format(hourdate);
            String formattedminute = minuteformatter.format(hourdate);

            Log.v(StorybookContentProvider.TAG_LOG, "formattedhour" + Integer.parseInt(formattedminute) + formattedminute);


            as.setDate(format);
            as.setRangeStart("");
            as.setRangeFinish("");
            as.setHour(Integer.parseInt(formattedhour));
            Log.v(StorybookContentProvider.TAG_LOG, "formattedhoursaving" + Integer.parseInt(formattedminute));
            as.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(formattedminute));
            as.setTabColor(as.tabHost, true);
```

The problem is: `formattedhour` is formatted in a way that I want (if selected `03` it returns `03`), but if I do `Integer.parseInt(formattedhour)`, it returns 3! It removes the format. Is this an error?

Comment: All this text & code just for asking if `Integer.parseInt ("03")` returns `3` ? well yes, that's what parseInt does. Read the [*manual*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))!

Comment: 3 and 03 are the same, they both represent three

Answer (score 3):

There is no bug. It is working as expected.

Formatting is for display purpose, if you want 03, then use formatted one. Leading zero hasd different meaning while using with integer, that is why it will be treated as 3.

Comment: A leading zero in a Java integer literal is significant - it indicates that the value is octal rather than decimal.  This isn't a problem parsing strings with leading zeroes using the one-argument version of `parseInt` because it assumes you want a decimal interpretation, but it can be a problem if you declare something like `int x = 030`, which assigns the decimal value 24 to x.

Comment: @DanDyer: You are correct. That skipped my mind. Deleted unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete the zero that is on the left of the integer, then it should work well